# right R package for portfolio optimization using nonlinear constraints

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio, nonlinear-optimization

I am currently looking at rewriting a commercial "back-box" portfolio optimiser, data in -> results out. I want to move away and use my own R version of it, so far a have to implementations working for my equality constraints, "solve.QP" and "constrOptim".

My problem now is the more I move towards nonlinear constraints (especially turnover limitations and transaction costs) the less information I find, would be great if someone could recommend a package, best case already a finance package or a more general mathematical one. The few packages I read along the lines so far were, "nloptr","fportfolio" and sometimes "rmetrics".

Any examples would also be highly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turnover constraints involve an absolute value. This can be linearized. So you can use your existing solver.

Linear transaction cost: same story. If your transaction cost have a fixed cost structure then things become more complicated. That may require an MIQP solver.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, do you have any sources where I can read up on this or can look at any concrete examples ?

Comment: Some results from Google:  [Portfolio optimization with linear and fixed
transaction costs](https://faculty.washington.edu/mfazel/portfolio-final.pdf) and [Portfolio Optimization with Transaction Costs](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.560.6161&rep=rep1&type=pdf). May be ask the experts at http://quant.stackexchange.com/ for better references. (I am not an expert in this field although I often help out when the optimization problems become more difficult to model or to solve).